# "unable to resolve class GradleException" Error

Tags: flutter, dart

I am creating my project and when trying to run it it shows me this error, I have not programmed anything I just wanted to run the default app

[bug image](https://i.stack.imgur.com/aOVI8.jpg)

Comment: Hello and welcome to stackoverflow. It is etiquette here to post the code and error message as text, not as an image. You can copy+paste it from your code editor and format it nicely with the text editing tools here

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The complete error message reads

> Unexpected token. u @ line 12, column 2

And if you look in line 12, right below the text "unable to resolve class GradleException", then you see a closing bracket and an extra "u".

Apparently this is an accidental typo. Remote that u and try again